# How can I get a date object from timestamp firebase kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
data class Message(
var message:String,
var id:String,
var receiverID:String,
@ServerTimestamp
var date: Date? = null,
var isChecked:Boolean,
var type:String,
```

)

This is the model of my message

```
val message = Message(text, id, receiverUser.uid, null, false, MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT)
    database
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
        .add(message)
    mBinding.typeMessageField.setText(null)
```

This is how I add a message, I pass the date value as `null` so it generates itself, but I don't understand how I can get the generated time from there to display it on the screen and sort the list of messages, because when I try to get the value, I can't translate it to date, or I get NullPointerException.

```
database
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!!)
        .collection(KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
        .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
            var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
            if (error != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            } else {
                if (value == null) {
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                } else {

                    for (documentChange in value.documentChanges) {
                        if (documentChange.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            var doc = documentChange.document
                            if (doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID) == receiverUser.uid) {
                                var text = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var id = doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_ID).toString()
                                var receiverId =
                                    doc.getString(KEY_MESSAGE_RECEIVER_ID).toString()
                                var date = doc.getTimestamp(KEY_MESSAGE_DATE)?.toDate()

                                var isChecked = doc.getBoolean(KEY_MESSAGE_ISCHECKED)!!
                                var type = doc.getString(KEY_TYPE_MESSAGE).toString()
                                var message =
                                    Message(text, id, receiverId, date, isChecked, type)
                                if (message !in messages) {
                                    messages.add(message)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    messages.sortBy { it -> it.date }
                    var messages_test = ArrayList(messages)
                    userChatAdpater.updateList(messages_test)
                    if (messages.size != 0) {
                        mBinding.rvUserChat.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is message listener

Comment: Have you tried to not initialize it and leave everything further to the annotation? The docs say *If a POJO being written contains `null` for a `@ServerTimestamp`-annotated field, it will be replaced with a server-generated timestamp.*, but I would try a `var date: Date?` without explicitly setting it to `null`.

Comment: If I just write var date: Date, I need to pass some value to the constructor, if I pass null there will be nullPointerException, but if I restart the application the messages are displayed correctly, I can not pass anything to the constructor either

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in the constructor `null` to the `date` field, that field will have the value of null in the database. Which most likely is not what you want. To solve this, when you create an object of type Message class, don't pass anything to the `date` field. Firebase servers will read your `date` field, as it is a ServerTimestamp (see the annotation), and it will populate that field with the server timestamp accordingly. So you should have something like this:

```
val message = Message(text, id, receiverUser.uid, false, MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT)
```

See, there is no `null` value. However, the field should remain the same in your class:

```
@ServerTimestamp
var date: Date? = null,
```

Don't delete null from the class.

Comment: I did so, but I have a message listener and when I send a message it triggers and gives out null, because of this the message is not displayed, but if you reopen the fragment with chat, all messages are displayed correctly

Comment: I added the listener code to the question text

Comment: In general, other questions that derive from the initial one should be considered new questions. So please post a new separate question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Hey Danil. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me a lot already.

Comment: Good to hear that.

Comment: @AlexMomo it helped only partially I created a new question